# calling a method multiple times, is there a more productive way of doing it?

Tags: php, class, methods, return

I have a user registration script. At one stage I call a method three times. Once to check if the method returns true, else if it doesn't, does it return a string (containing an error message) and if it does get the returned string and place it in a variable.

Is the a more productive way of doing this so that I only need to call the method once? But still get all answers I need?

Heres the code:

```
//check thumbnail is present and good
            if($register->checkThumb()){
                //send image to permanent image directory
                $register->moveUploadedImage();

                //if the thumbnail failed validation put the error message in variable
            }else if(is_string($register->checkThumb())){
                $message = $register->checkThumb();

            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    $thumb = $register->checkThumb(); //call method once and save in variable
   /* using just if($thumb) would return always true, because 
      the function may returns an errormessage on failure 
      which is ja string, which is not empty, not 0, not false == true */
    if($thumb === true){
      //send image to permanent image directory
      $register->moveUploadedImage();
    }else{ //so then it's enough to ask for error this way
      $message = $thumb;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can assign variable in if statement,

```
if($checked = $register->checkThumb()){
    //send image to permanent image directory
    $register->moveUploadedImage();

    //if the thumbnail failed validation put the error message in variable
}else if(is_string($checked)){
    $message = $checked;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do as follows:

```
if(!($check_thumb_retvalue = $register->checkThumb())) {
  //send image to permanent image directory
  $register->moveUploadedImage();

//if the thumbnail failed validation put the error message in variable
}
else if(is_string($check_thumb_retvalue)) {
  $message = $register->checkThumb();
}
```

or, more readable:

```
$check_thumb_retvalue = $register->checkThumb();
if(!$check_thumb_retvalue){
  //send image to permanent image directory
  $register->moveUploadedImage();
}
//if the thumbnail failed validation put the error message in variable
else if(is_string($check_thumb_retvalue)) {
  $message = $check_thumb_retvalue;
}
```

LG,
 CK

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
        $result = $register->checkThumb();
        if($result){
            //send image to permanent image directory
            $register->moveUploadedImage();

            //if the thumbnail failed validation put the error message in variable
        }else if(is_string($result)){
            $message = $result;

        }
```

But your code is fine, unless the method is extremely expensive there isn't going to be any noticeable difference at all.

Answer (score 1):

You can assign result to variable, and then check that variable.
Also, when you check if variable is true, you should do it with operator ===. Otherwise, if function returns non empty string, it will also be qualified as true. Operator === checks for type, so that way only boolean variable of value true will pass.

```
$result = $register->checkThumb();
if($result === true) {
    $register->moveUploadedImage();
} else if (is_string($result)){
    $message = $result;
}
```